# How long can he be the Hulk before he has to turn back into a puny human?

Tags: comics, marvel, the-incredible-hulk

It used to be: "The madder Hulk gets, the stronger Hulk gets!" and then he'd revert back when he calmed down. I always assumed it was to recharge. Now it appears Bruce Banner can change into the Hulk at will. What is the longest amount of time (either Dr. David or Bruce) Banner maintained his Hulk alter-ego before he had to turn back into a puny human?

Comment: If you count the MCU, Banner stays as the Hulk for two years in *Thor Ragnarok*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if anyone is keeping track, so I doubt there's an official record of the *longest* amount of time that Banner has stayed the Hulk.  There have been several periods that stretched on for months where he stayed in his green Hulk form though.  This happened once during the [Merged Hulk/Professor](http://www.incrediblehulkonline.com/professor.html) incarnation, which was basically the mind of Bruce Banner in control of the Hulk's physical form, and more recently during the events of [Planet Hulk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Hulk) through the end of [World War Hulk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_Hulk).

Comment: World War Hulk is notable for Banner staying in Hulk form even while HAPPY, and Hulk voluntarily returning to Banner's form...and Banner knowing what Hulk's been up to.  The impression given is that he could remain the Hulk indefinitely.

Comment: Incidentally, I recall there being a period during the Professor phase in the '90s where if he got into a rage, it was the reverse -- the rage personality would emerge, but he would turn into the human form.

Comment: It's possible that in the timeline leading to the [Maestro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maestro_%28comics%29) future in *The Incredible Hulk: Future Imperfect*,  Hulk was continuously in the green form for about a century. In particular, once he turned to evil as the Maestro, he apparently stayed green, as far as was mentioned.

Comment: @JacobC. I remember that brief "Banner Hulk" period. There have been a handful incarnations of it over the years, one I think during the Red Hulk run. There was also a short run (only a couple of issues if I remember right) way back when it was Banner's head on the Hulk's body.

Comment: Speaking of *The Incredible Hulk: Future Imperfect* (in which Hulk is transported to the future to fight his future tyrant self), I just remembered that my copy (1994 TPB collecting vols. 1&2) has an imperfection jumping the *reader* into the future. That is, it has a misprint where of a couple of pages from later in the book were accidentally swapped with pages earlier in the book. (It was a bit confusing on first read!) I used to figure that many copies in that run must have had the same misprint, but looking around on the Web, I don't see any mention of the error, so perhaps mine is rare.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is actually a simple one.

Bruce Banner, essentially, represents the calm feelings in the Banner/Hulk creature. He is the weakness in the Hulk and this is why the Hulk has always despised him.

As shown several times, the Hulk can stay angry indefinitely, while awake and with Banner in him. When, in one comic, Bruce Banner reaches the end of his natural lifespan, the Hulk essentially makes himself immortal by staying angry forever. However, it is important to note that at this point, Banner is essentially dead and gone, affording the Hulk the ability.

With Banner in and against him he can stay the Hulk as long as he doesn't calm down or sleep. Without Banner or in accordance with Banner (as seen with several versions of the Hulk), he never needs to change back.

Answer (score 1):

In *Thor Ragnarok* movie, Banner stayed as Hulk for 2 years and he would have remained that way if he hadn't seen and heard Black Widow's message.

So, the answer is "Lifetime".